# Why was my flag requesting deletion declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderators

So, I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310395/mvc4-dropdownlistfor-can-not-post-value).

I flagged it with a custom flag:

> This question should be deleted since it is useless to anyone, as the posted code is not incorrect, and the askers problem was somewhere else and did not bother to supply any additional information that might make this question useful to others.

This was rejected with

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this the very definition of content that requires the intervention of a moderator (since we can't delete questions ourselves as mere non-moderator users)?

There used to be an ability to nominate a question for deletion after it was closed, but this seems to be gone now that questions are "put on hold" rather than closed.

Granted, the question is not offensive, or spam, or anything like that, but it's junk. It clogs up the system, it has no value because the posted question was in regards to code that had nothing wrong with it, and the asker acknowledge the problem was somewhere else in code they did not post.

So how does this benefit anyone on the site or anyone in the future?  It should be deleted.  And we, as users can't do that.

I'm somewhat miffed at the implication that I'm "wasting moderators' time" or something based on the response.

Yet moderators are busy marking questions as duplicates (things we as users *can* do), so what's the deal here?

Comment: How long until you can cast a delete vote?

Comment: You *are* wasting moderator's time. Users can (and do) delete (and undelete) questions every single day, and there's even a [queue for them](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today). I'm amazed that someone with your reputation level isn't aware of how SO works by now, especially the 10K tools.

Comment: "Yet moderators are busy marking questions as duplicates (things we as users *can* do), so what's the deal here?" Not everything we do is in response to flags. We use the site too, you know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an excerpt from the [Access to Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege page:

> **When should I delete questions?**
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion.
>
> This restriction is removed for trusted users when a post scores -3 or lower.

So, while 10K users need to wait a couple days, at your privilege level (trusted user) you could vote to delete immediately, assuming the score dropped lower (as of now, it's not -3).

I imagine that's why your flag was declined for the given reason. Not saying that the mods aren't capable of doing something, but in this case it's not something *requiring* their specific abilities.

Comment: Well, as usual, it's not always easy to find this information and the constantly changing behavior of the site makes things unpredictable sometimes.  In any event, I do notice it says at the end "If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please flag it for community moderator attention."

Answer (score 7):

There's already a process in place for this, close the question and it will later be eligible for deletion (after the five day "on hold" period is up). This is not something that requires a moderator to step in, so it shouldn't have been flagged. We can't stop to look at every question that gets closed.

Comment: This particular question is even eligible for auto-deletion after 9 days. :)

Comment: Quit messing around by closing stuff and [do some mod things already...gosh!](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/a3eg_ZlmcGGj-YlQo4Zd8VUrCKtYJdmPZ1WspkEU44J6KuLmIXf_9cDF6Q_Md4s59jkNcdPg03I=w1831-h851)

Comment: It's really hard to keep track of the changing rules as far as this sort of thing goes.  It used to be that you could vote to delete immediately after close.